# Jmeter integration with Git Hub ( How to push/Pull jmx,parameter files to Git)

Tags: github, jmeter

Need to Save Jmeter JMX/data files to github from Jmeter. How to point jmeter datafiles/parameter files to GIT files.  While running the test jmeter need to pull latest datafiles from GIT

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to achieve, please provide more details.

Comment: @sand have you solved your issue?

Answer (score 2):

I downloaded GitHub Desktop from [here](https://desktop.github.com/).

Link your GitHub account and then create or clone a repo.

Then any files edited within that directory will be recognised and can be pushed to GitHub, including jmx files.

Can also easily add files/folders/results/HTMLreports etc easily from your local machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload an existing file to a GitHub repository using the command line.

1. Copy the JMX\data files you'd like to push to GitHub into the local directory that was cloned from the repository.
2. Run Git Bash.
3. Change the working directory to your local repository.
4. Add files to commit in your local repo:

   ```
   git add test.jmx
   ```
5. Commit files to your local repo:

   ```
   git commit -m 'Some comment text'
   ```
6. Push your files from local repo to GitHub

   ```
   git push origin your-branch-name
   ```